# USB Installation - Scrambled Screen

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation

I have a 2010 Toshiba Qosmio X505 that I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on. I have downloaded the Ubuntu 14.04 ISO, and created a bootable USB as in the instructions given here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

I have already deleted the old OS, and am starting from a clean slate. In some misguided experiments with Arch Linux, I might have changed the file system to ext4 (but more on that only if it is relevant). When I try to install Ubuntu, I get the BIOS bootloader screen (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Identifying_if_the_computer_boots_the_Ubuntu_DVD_in_EFI_mode). After this point, the screen is scrambled, I can't tell what happens.

My guess is that this has to do with an older BIOS or something to do with the file system on the laptop, but some direction in solving this problem would be appreciated. Can provide any other information that might help diagnose this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running into a graphics issue. If you press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit you will see:

[image]

then press <kbd>F6</kbd> and select `nomodeset`. This will allow you to continue to the next screen and finish the installation.

After that, you will probably have to update your graphics drivers.  If you would run into problems there, just [ask a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and have your graphics hardware details ready.

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) Just click the little grey check-mark under the "0" now.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0 and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: Yes, figured this out yesterday.  Nvidia graphics card issues. Will mark this as accepted.

Comment: Thanks!  I should have looked at your question yesterday to save you time!  Did you try xorg-edgers already?  Do you have a  question on NVidia open? (I have an NVidia too and solved all my problems with them)

Comment: Nope straight up `apt-get install nvidia-current`. Figuring out `nomodeset` was a pain though since I had never done that before. What are `xorg-edgers`?

Comment: If your set-up works, praise yourself lucky and don't touch it!

Now, if you would run into future problems with NVidia: one address: https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: Did I mention not to touch your setup if it works?  :P  If you still want to touch it, take a system backup first! [What's a good back-up strategy for 1 desktop PC?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)